# Ubuntu Touch - Missed calls notification panel options

Tags: ubuntu-touch, notification

These days, if you have not got someone number, they may call your phone so you both have each others number. If you do not pick the phone up, in your notification panel you have the option to "Message" or "Call" the number back. If you wish to add the number to your contacts, you need to click on the call option and then press "Add Contact" rather than calling. It would be better to have the "Add to contacts" option in the notification panel too. Is there a setting that I can activate to have this option in my notification panel or will I need to raise this in Launchpad.

Comment: I have raised this in Launchpad under - https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/archipel-agent-iphone-notification/+bug/1598989

Comment: I have added a comment to this bug report in Launchpad as nearly a month and no movement.